# How can retrieve the name of the placement (Facebook Audience Network)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, audience

With the Facebook Audience Network API i have the placement id, but not the placement name

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/XXX/app_insights/app_event/?period=daily&event_name=fb_ad_network_imp&aggregateBy=COUNT&breakdowns[0]=placement&access_token=XXX


{
     "time": "2016-09-21T07:00:00+0000",
     "value": "36785",
     "breakdowns": {
        "placement": "176682892738688"
     }
  },
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Did you find the way?

Comment: @RhinoLarva Nope i still searching... ;(

Comment: @did anyone get to resolve this ?

Comment: hey did anyone get solution for this??

Answer (score 0):

**API Doc Ref:**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/atlas-api/reference/api/placements/v2.11#readplacements

**API Request:**

https://graph.facebook.com/{API_VERSION}/{PLACEMENT_ID}

but the token here is not your user token, from the doc:

```
A user access token with Atlas API capability is required.
```

but the Atlas pages sounds be removed.

I find a method to get the token from the response of 'https://business.facebook.com/pub/property/?business_id={bussiness_id}&property_id={property_id}'

**the response abstract str:**

"require":[["WebApiApplication","init",["ReactRenderer","PubXRootContainer.react","__inst_d496507d_0_0","__elem_a588f507_0_0"],["{TARGET TOKEN}","{ids}",{"__m":"ReactRenderer"},"constructAndRenderCompone

[image]